# Connecting Epson XP-335 Scanner after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: epson

Epson has pushed the version after 16.04. Last time I got that Epson XP-332-335 installed using the instructions on this site, but I can't find a solution for version 22.04.

Comment: This is an English only site. Please use a tool like Google translate and post the question in English. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a special solution for 22.04. Install Epson driver from their site.

Comment: That is https://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the driver from [Epson Support Site](https://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php)

It supports XP-335 and Ubuntu 22.04.